# Introducir por teclado el nombre del objeto

Tags: java, object, scanner, java-util-scanner

Antes que nada, aprovecho para presentarme, soy Pablo y estoy comenzando a estudiar programación. Os escribo porque tengo un ejercicio de Java con una clase Mascota con diversos atributos.

Permito que el usuario inserte los valores de la mascota con el teclado de la siguiente forma:

```java
    `public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

    `   System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de mascota:");
        String tipo = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de tu mascota:");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce la raza de " + nombre + ":");
        String raza = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce la edad de " + nombre + ":");
        int edad = sc.nextInt();`
```

Posteriormente, creo el objeto, la mascota, teniendo que asignarle manualmente el nombre al objeto, en este caso "dali".

```java
    `   Mascota dali = new Mascota(raza, nombre, edad);`
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el nombre del objeto sea el que introduce el usuario con el teclado?

Gracias de antemano :)

Saludos!

Comment: Puedes agregar un atributo más en la clase `Mascota`, de ese modo le pides al usuario que ingrese el nombre del objeto y lo almacenas en ese atributo.

Comment: Si, de hecho la clase ya tiene el atributo nombre. La duda es si puedo hacer que el valor que ingrese el usuario para el atributo nombre, aplique automáticamente al nombre del objeto. Es decir si el usuario a “Introduce el nombre de tu mascota” responde “Pepe”,  automáticamente al objeto se le asigne esa denominación, es decir, sea “Mascota pepe = new Mascota(raza, nombre, edad);”.

Comment: Lo que dices no es posible de hacerlo, debido a que el nombre del objeto es una simple identificación para el programador, cuando el código se compile, ese nombre deja de existir.

Comment: @MrDave1999 ah ok! aclarado. Estoy empezando y pensaba que habría manera. Mil gracias!